# Manually add a line in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, line

I have a data in the following format

```
data<-data.frame(id  = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
             school= c("school1", "school1", "school1","school1", "school2", "school2"), 
             time = rep(c("pre", "post"), 3),
             type = rep(c("ctr", "ctr", "exp"), each =2),
             values = c(3.4, 3.4, 3.2, 4.1, 3.3, 4.3))
```

I created a plot with the means in each time per condition using the following code

```
p1<-ggline(data, x = "time", y = "values", color = "type",
       add = "mean",
       palette = c("#bb00af", "#00bb6a", "#7393B3"))
```

[image: Plot values per time and condition]
Now I want to create a different plot for each school in which I can show the results for type and the results for the school, so I tried:

```
l1<- geom_line(aes(y = mean(data$values), colour = "school1"),
group = type)
p1+l1
```

But it is not ploting the line.
[image: Plot 1 + line for school1]

I would like to get a similar line as the green and purple ones, but in blue for the mean for the school in the pre and post measurements. Any ideas on how can I get what I want, please? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could `filter` a subset of the categorical and give it a `colour` to the `palette` like this:

```r
library(ggpubr)
library(dplyr)

p1<-ggline(data, x = "time", y = "values", color = "type",
           add = "mean",
           palette = c("#bb00af", "#00bb6a", "#7393B3", "yellow")) +
  geom_line(data %>%
               filter(school == "school1"),
             mapping = aes(y = values, colour = "school1"))

p1
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, but why the line does not link pre and post time for school1? I want a line like the others two...

Comment: Hi @Anita-, Then you could add `group = type` in the `aes` of `geom_line`.

Comment: Thank you! It still does not show the line. I also added mean() because I guessed it is ploting all the observations, but it still does not work :(

Comment: I edited the post including your suggestions and with the outcome I get. I hope someone can help me, thank you!

Comment: Heyyyy! I am sorry, it did work with your suggestion, adding both group = type and the previous code you shared. Sorry and thank you very much again!

Comment: Hello! I am sorry to re-ask a question here again, but after many essays I realized that the line it is plotting per school it only contains the "post" value... Any ideas on how to plot both "pre" and "post" values, please?